# recursive ajax calls not executing script included inbetween the recursion

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a recursive Ajax call that work properly (PhP script called do his job, recursion is working, everything is fine) EXCEPT that in between the ajax calls i try to update a input text value to show the progress and it only updates once the whole loop is done.

Why is the line

```
$('#start_'+code_regional).val(msg);
```

not executing ?

```
function addLeads(code_regional, phone_numbers_start)
    {
        var databases = [];
        var file = document.getElementById('file_'+code_regional).files[0];

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('selectedDatabases', JSON.stringify(databases));
        formData.append('code_regional', code_regional);
        formData.append('phone_numbers_start', phone_numbers_start);
        formData.append('phone_numbers_end', $('#end_'+code_regional).val());
        formData.append('filePath', file);

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'execute.php',
           data: formData,
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success: function(msg){
                $('#start_'+code_regional).val(msg);
                if(msg < $('#end_'+code_regional).val())
                {
                    addLeads(code_regional, msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#start_'+code_regional).val($('#end_'+code_regional).val());
                }
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the line `if(msg < $('#end_'+code_regional).val())` supposed to check ? what kind of value is `msg` supposed to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `msg` is an integer, you should compare integers instead of strings:

`if( parseInt(msg,10) < parseInt($('#end_'+code_regional).val(),10) )`

If it's still failing, try to add a `console.log(...)` before and after the test to know what's going on.

Comment: That isn't my problem, the comparison is working as intended, but yes this could be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean *in between the ajax calls*? The code tells me, "if msg is less than y, call addLeads again, otherwise update the start field". So that's not tracking progress, the start field is only updated at the end. If you want to always update, move the update line outside the conditional.

Comment: the start field is only updated at the end -

thats not correct, check code again please

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? *If you want to always update, move the update line outside the conditional.*